# StoreKit background download

Tags: ios, background, download, storekit

According to the In-App Purchasing Programming Guide under [Delivering Associated Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW9)

> Additionally, Apple-hosted content automatically downloads in the background even if your app isn’t running.

I have tested this in sandbox mode on my iPad and it does not work. After I purchase an item and downloading begins, I press the home button. The app goes to the background. Then I re-open the app. Then I get an error. To be specific I get `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` for the transaction associated to the download.

Do I need to do anything specific to support downloading content in the background?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Did you found out any solution to this ?

Comment: No I did not. I contacted Apple tech support but they simply told me to file a bug report. I did that back in May 2014 and so far they have not answered the bug report.